# Spfx Webpart Bingmap doesn't render at first load

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, map

I would like very much to be helped with this. basically I have a spfx react webpart in which I intend to load a bingmap.
What I coded is something very simple:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript("https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol").then(
      () => {
        
        if (Microsoft.Maps && this.mapDivRef.current) {
          this.mapsInstance = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.mapDivRef.current, {
            credentials: "XXXXX",
            customMapStyle: mapStyle,
            zoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 4,
            enableClickableLogo: false,
            showLocateMeButton: true,
            showTrafficButton: false,
            showTermsLink: false,
            disableBirdseye: true,
            disableStreetside: true,
            showDashboard: false,
            showBreadcrumb: false,
            showLogo: false,
            showMapTypeSelector: false,
            allowHidingLabelsOfRoad: true,
            showScalebar: false,
            labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden,
  
});
```

The problem with this implementation is that at the first load the map doesn't show up alothough I receive no errors. if after the first load, I navigate the SPO site and then get back to the page where the map webpart is, it works normally (same thing as if i hit the modify page button, it will render normally).

Can please anyone help? I am almost hopeless.
Thanks!